# How to add dynamic parameter in dataSources?

Tags: sapui5

In [Doc of Descripter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html), there are only `odataVersion`, `localUri`, `annotations` and `maxAge` in `settings` of `dataSources`, what if I want to add a dynamic parameter such as Date in url?

Such as :

```
"dataSources": {
     "mainService": {
         "uri": "getData?Date=" + new Date(),
         "type": "JSON"
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think it is no possible from this configuration. You need a date in URl to get rid of cached data? What if you set maxAge to 0, would it help?

Comment: for caching there are different mechanisms you should use. what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Aggregation Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bf71375454654b44af01379a3c3a6273.html) to solved this problem:

```
        //worklist.controller.js
        onInit : function(oEvent) {               
            const oView = this.getView(),
            oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(),
            oTable = oView.byId("table");

            oTable.setBusy(true);

            oModel.loadData("getData?Date=" + new Date());
            oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
                oTable.setBusy(false);
            });

            //Set a name for oModel so that it won't confused with my mainService
            oView.setModel(oModel, "myModel");      
        },

        //worklist.view.xml
        <Table
            id="table"
            items="{
                path: 'myModel>/'
            }">
            <columns>
                <Column><Text text="ID"/></Column>
            </columns>

            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{myModel>ID}"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```